# applying global style for tds except tds with custom made select element

Tags: html, css

I applied a global style `overflow: hidden` for all tds of a table except the ones with a custom made select element as its child.

snippets:
css:

```
th, td {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

html:

```
<td>
  <select class="ks-selectList">
    <option>data 1.2</option>
    <option>data 2.2</option>
    <option>data 3.2</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

javascript:

```
// Iterate over each select element
$('.ks-selectList').each(function () {

    // Cache the number of options
    var $this = $(this),
        numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

    $this.css("visibility", "hidden");

    // Wrap the select element in a div
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

    // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
    $this.after('<div class="select-content"></div>');

    // Cache the styled div
    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-content');

    // Show the first select option in the styled div
    $styledSelect.wrapInner('<span>'+$this.children('option').eq(0).text()+'</span>');
    // Insert an unordered list after the styled div and also cache the list
    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    // Insert a list item into the unordered list for each select option
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }

    // Cache the list items
    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

    // Show the unordered list when the styled div is clicked (also hides it if the div is clicked again)
    $styledSelect.click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('div.select-content.active').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.options').hide();
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.options').toggle();
    });

    // Hides the unordered list when a list item is clicked and updates the styled div to show the selected list item
    // Updates the select element to have the value of the equivalent option
    $listItems.click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $list.hide();
    });

    // Hides the unordered list when clicking outside of it
    $(document).click(function () {
        $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        $list.hide();
    });

});
```

result:
[screenshot #1](http://screencast.com/t/PK14vGiv3eGX)

expected result:
[screenshot #2](http://screencast.com/t/XKx64QQzQF)

I know I can override this using class, however I want to do this without using class.

Comment: Show the relevant HTML

Comment: You cannot create a CSS rule to style an element based on its children

Comment: @SW4 - but is it possible to get the result that I expect?

Comment: Can you create a working JSFiddle with your code? I placed the code that you pasted here on one but the results are completely different to the screenshot you posted as your result. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/c8cfv60x/